Ciphertext created by elliptic curve key
I'm looking to decrypt a message using the following code snippet, but I'm unsure how to proceed. I have a secret key and an encrypted message, and I believe it involves the secp384r1 elliptic curve. Here’s the code I'm working with:
secret_key = 0x123456789abcdef

enc_message = "041b432a3df169d33f0748c8322cb5a413bb7239b45c3e34aa9ac2d70fec8146dd81439e1c12eca49a980b60df7c45abe0beb387173715e43eab897b9a50a254da62e0bcb74b94f1eed1e26490291a76d86309db87026dac120af9323dd16cf008045b8c7f1df30e9883d37e72f68df6db2a98d1c87619f98d2eeb036349fcd8d41f31e3fd893a889ba264b90712e6b9aaabffbca20108fe87881c7c778a8177e5e62303777880e0665e628d31bb0378333abd24c81b638e61dfe97439223445b20c"

Could someone help me understand how to decrypt this message? Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Hint: enc_message could be the concatenation of two points on the curve secp384r1, formatted in uncompressed form, which is 04, X-coordinate, Y coordinate (big-endian over fixed width). Parameters for secp384r1 parameters let you verify this. This could be some variation of ElGamal encryption, which ciphertext consist of two group elements, but I would not bet the house on that. The secret (not private) key is indeed shorter than we'd expect for that (it would need padding with 91 zeroes). I'd look at the context around that CTF.
